# Getting error "cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Couldn't load plugin class: com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter."

Tags: junit, cucumber, extentreports

I am trying to generate Extent report for my test run using Junit cucumber ,but i am getting error

```
"cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Couldn't load plugin class: com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter. It does not implement cucumber.api.Plugin "
```

My Error trace is as follows -:

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Couldn't load plugin class: com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter. It does not implement cucumber.api.Plugin
    at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.loadClass(PluginFactory.java:179)
    at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.pluginClass(PluginFactory.java:166)
    at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.getPluginClass(PluginFactory.java:223)
    at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.isFormatterName(PluginFactory.java:201)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptionsFactory.addPlugins(RuntimeOptionsFactory.java:94)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptionsFactory.buildArgsFromOptions(RuntimeOptionsFactory.java:41)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptionsFactory.create(RuntimeOptionsFactory.java:26)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

My Pom.xml has following dependencies -:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
            <version>1.27</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.13</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency> <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId> <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId> 
            <version>3.8.1</version> </dependency> 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>2.41.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

My Runner class is as Follows -:

```
package com.cumberpr2.Runner;

import java.io.File;

import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import com.cucumber.listener.ExtentProperties;
import com.cucumber.listener.Reporter;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features= {"src/test/java/com/cumberpr2/First/feature"},glue= {"com/cumberpr2/step"},
monochrome=true,tags= {"@bvt,@sanity"},plugin={"com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:target/cucumber/report1.html"} 
)
//{"pretty","html:target/cucumber","com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter"}
public class Runner1 {

     @AfterClass
        public static void teardown() {
            Reporter.loadXMLConfig(new File("/src/test/java/com/cumberpr2/step/Extent-Config.xml"));

            Reporter.setSystemInfo("os", "windows OSX");
            Reporter.setTestRunnerOutput("Sample test runner output message");
        }

    /* @BeforeClass
     public static void setup() {
         ExtentProperties extentProperties = ExtentProperties.INSTANCE;
         extentProperties.setReportPath("output/myreport.html");
         extentProperties.setExtentXServerUrl("http://localhost:1337");
         extentProperties.setProjectName("MyProject");
     }*/


}
```

My Folder structure is as follows -:  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ek06R.png

[enter image description here][1]

Comment: Seems to be a known issue. Extent report does not support cucumber 2 yet. https://github.com/email2vimalraj/CucumberExtentReporter/issues/75

Comment: @Grasshopper thanks

Answer (score 4):

After many days searching for a solution to this problem that was also happening to me, I discovered the cause (at least that worked for me).
Apparently, the pluggin com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter or
com.vimalselvam.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter (for cucumber-extentreports version 3.1.1+) only works with the cucumber of the info.cukes package.

```
<! - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java ->
<dependency>
<groupId>info.cukes</ groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>    
<version>1.2.5</ version>
</dependency>
```

To use ExtentReports with the most current cucumber versions (package io.cucumber from versions 2.X.X onwards) you need to add the cucumber-adapter plugin.

For each X version of cucumber, there is an adapter, such as for cucumber version 4.X.X the extentreports-cucumber4-adapter dependency is required.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
<artifactId>extentreports-cucumber4-adapter</artifactId>
<version>1.0.7</version>
</dependency>
```

And in the class Runner you should replace the plugin:

> "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:"

by

> "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:"

For an example of using cucumber 4 with extent reports follow the GitHub link I found:

> https://github.com/foursyth/extentreports-cucumber4-example

For versions 2.X.X and 3.X.X follow the same principles as 4.X.X

ExtentReport settings specification link of all versions:

> http://extentreports.com/documentation/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

**Advise** is to upgrade your **cucumber v to 4.x.x.** Doing so would not only resolve your error rather you would be able to generate consolidated report during parallel execution as well without creating runners manually.

**There are 2 ways of implementing extent report in Cucumber :**

**1. Using Cucumber-JVM 4 adapter for Extent Framework(extentreports-cucumber4-adapter)** - Beauty is, you do not need to write any code any where to generate report this way except from setting adapter in runner below.

Add adapter dependency under POM.XML

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber4-adapter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

*Add the com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter plugin to the runner.*

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:"})
public class RunCukesTest {
    // ..
}
```

*Report Output Directory - ../Project Directory/test-output/HtmlReport*

**2. Adding aventstack dependency under POM.XML**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

In this workflow, *Do not Add the com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter plugin to the runner.*